# Why is there a red cross over app in android studio?

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

Im a complete beginner to android studio. And Im facing a crisis when I try to run this app. Any detailed solution will be very helpful and every time I open android studio there is a red cross over app.[image of prob;em](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f8LyG.png)

Comment: Please don't post images of code or errors; see [ask].

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.